# Function to shorten a specific string

Tags: php, string

I have this string:

```
$str="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg";
```

Is there a built-in php function that can shorten it by removing the `._SL110_.jpg` part, so that the result will be:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL
```

Comment: Is `._SL110_.jpg` going to be a constant value, or is it a value that can vary?

Comment: not sure it its constant. but what Im sure of is that anything after the "dot" followed by the underscore needs to be stripped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using:

```
$tmp = explode("._", $str);
```

and then using `$tmp[0]` for your purpose, if you make sure the part you want to get rid of is always separated by "._" (dot-underscore) symbols.

Comment: using $tmp[0] only outputs the string before the first "dot" and doesnt serve the purpose.

Comment: thanks to all and thank you also lenik. I use your simplified code and it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

no, there's not any built in URL shortener php function, if you want to do something similar you can use the substring or create a function that generates a short link and stores the long and short value somewhere in database and display only the short one.

Answer (score 1):

well, it depends if you need a regexp replace (if you don't know the complete value) or if you can do a simple str_replace like below:

```
$str = str_replace(".SL110.jpg", "", "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg");
```

Comment: this doesn't work Johannes. I tried it but its not replacing.

Comment: it will work only if the value to be replaced is known. but what if its not? only the "dot" followed by the underscore is known and the rest of the string all the way to .jpg might vary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace().

For example `preg_replace("/\.[^\.]+\.jpg$/i", "", $str);`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not (at least not directly). Such URL shorteners usually generate unique ID and remember your original URL and generated ID. When you enter such url, you start a script, which looks for given ID and then redirect to target URL.

If you want just cut of some portion of your string, then **assuming** that filename format is as you shown, just look for 1st dot and `substr()` to that place. Or

```
$tmp = explode('.', $filename);
$shortName = $tmp[0];
```

If suffix `._SL110_.jpg` is always there, then simply `str_replace('._SL110_.jpg', '', $filename)` could work.

**EDIT**

Above was example for filename only. Whole code would be:

```
$url = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg";
$urlTmp = explode('/', $url);
$fileNameTmp = explode( '.', $urlTmp[ count($urlTmp)-1 ] );

$urlTmp[ count($urlTmp)-1  ] = $fileNameTmp[0];
$newUrl = implode('/', $urlTmp );

printf("Old: %s\nNew: %s\n", $url, $newUrl);
```

gives:

```
Old: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg
New: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL
```

Comment: thats exactly the script. I only want to remove the appended ".SL110.jpg" that the script generated at the end so i can append my new image formatting. and I am asking if theres a built-in php function that can do that (scrape off) if theres any. thanks

Comment: that was fishing pole, not the fish. Example how to deal with file name. I added full code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this `substr($data,0,strpos($data,"._"))`, if what you want is to strip everything after "._"

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$str = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL._SL110_.jpg";
echo "<pre>";
```

A.

```
echo strrev(explode(".", strrev($str), 3)[2]) , PHP_EOL;
```

B.

```
echo pathinfo($str,PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . PATH_SEPARATOR . strstr(pathinfo($str,PATHINFO_FILENAME),".",true), PHP_EOL;
```

C.

```
echo preg_replace(sprintf("/.[^.]+\.%s$/i", pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), null, $str), PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418lsVTc0aL
```

[See Demo](http://eval.in/3841)

Comment: thanks Baba. it works but I prefer lenik code because its much more shorter.